# How do I pick up a value from a cell with the left cell value equals to something in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my table:

```
1 |  A   |  B    |   C  |
-------------------------
2 | Name | Value |   *  |
3 | Joe  | 10    |
4 | Bob  | 21    |
5 | Rick | 62    |
6 | Terry| 38    |
7 | Jim  | 77    |
```

I want the `*` cell be a value of a given name, like `Jim` in this case, it should be `77`. Is there any formula I can use?

I have made some guess but failed. My guess:

`=QUERY(A:B, "select B when A<>Jim")`

Comment: you want all of them to be picked up in corresponding order? like: c3=joe, c4=bob etc. or you want only "Jim" in C2?

Comment: ONLY Jim. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:B; "select B where A ='"&A7&"'"; 0)
```